# WordPress ajax request keeps returning 0 (wp_die() included)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am building a WordPress plugin(my first) and currently i am build the admin menu but i can't seem to be able to add some ajax functionality with my custom database.

Right now it always returns 0 even though i use wp_die().I also used die() and exit() but still the same.I moved the hooks for the callback in the view file but then i get 400 messages.At some point i managed to get the whole page as a response.

I made all this following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pO-FYVZv94 and the resources from the developer page of wordpress

My script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#test-form').submit(function () {

        data = {
            action: 'get_data'
        }

        $.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function (response) {
            alert(response);
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

view.php file

```php
<form action="" id="test-form" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="test-submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Press me!">
    </div>
</form>

<?php

 function data_callback(){
     //do the db stuff
     echo 'Hello from the callback';
     wp_die();
 }
```

admin class constructor

```php
public function __construct(){
   add_action('admin_menu', array($this,'setup_admin_menu'));
   add_action('wp_ajax_get_data', 'data_callback');
}
```

and this is how i load my script from the admin class among with the other libraries

```php
wp_enqueue_script('ajax-script', plugins_url('/assets/js/scripts.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
wp_localize_script('ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
```

Comment: Are you in the admin interface? Any error in console?

Comment: Add following line in __construct() `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_data', 'data_callback');`

Comment: @VidyaL yes and no

Comment: @ascsoftw still nothing.also it wouldn't help in this case

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$.ajax( {
    type : "POST",
    url : ajax_object.ajax_url,
    data : {action: "get_data"},
    success: function( response ) {
        alert( "Your vote could not be added" );
        alert( response );
    }
} );
```

Comment: i can see both alerts but still 0